# HTML: Table header not sync with table body

Tags: html, css

I created a table with fixed header and horizontal/vertical scroll bar but the body is not in sync.
Here is the jfiddle for it.
Please advice what i am doing wrong

http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/7033/

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200">
   <tr>
   <td>
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="200" >
     <tr style="color:white;background-color:grey">
        <th>Header 1</th>
        <th>Header 2</th>
     </tr>
   </table>
</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
<td>
   <div style="width:300px; height:100px; overflow:auto;">
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" width="400" >
       <tr>
         <td>new itemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td>
         <td>new item</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>new item</td>
         <td>new item</td>
       </tr>
          <tr>
         <td>new item</td>
         <td>new item</td>
       </tr>
   </table>  
   </div>
</td>
```

Comment: you have a 2 tables inside a table :O

Comment: yes to get horizontal and vertical scroll bar i have used 2 tables...can it be accomplished with 1 table?

Comment: yes it is achievable. I'll post my jsfiddle soon

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. got stuck with other stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its your **DOM** that creating that issue and by changing it you can easily acheive, what you're seeking.

There's no need to use extra `<table>` and using single `<table>` you do it as:

**HTML**:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="200">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>new itemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>new item</td>
        <td>new item</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS**:

```
.table-scroll {
    max-height: 200px;
    width:400px;
    overflow: auto;
    font-family: Arial;
}
table {
    background: #f5f5f5;
    border-collapse: separate;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 700px;
}
th {
    background: url(http://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png),  linear-gradient(#777, #444);
    border-left: 1px solid #555;
    border-right: 1px solid #777;
    border-top: 1px solid #555;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #999;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #000;
}
th:after {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0),  rgba(255, 255, 255, .08));
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 25%;
    left: 0;
    margin: 1px 0 0 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
}
th:first-child {
    border-left: 1px solid #777;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0 #999;
}
th:last-child {
    box-shadow: inset -1px 1px 0 #999;
}
td {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 300ms;
    word-break: break-all;
}
td:first-child {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 0 #fff;
}
td:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #e8e8e8;
    box-shadow: inset -1px 0 0 #fff;
}
tr {
    background: url(http://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png);
}
tr:nth-child(odd) td {
    background: #f1f1f1  url(http://jackrugile.com/images/misc/noise-diagonal.png);
}
tr:last-of-type td {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}
tr:last-of-type td:first-child {
    box-shadow: inset 1px -1px 0 #fff;

tr:last-of-type td:last-child {
    box-shadow: inset -1px -1px 0 #fff;
}
```

Please check my [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/za9f5jek/1)

> Please note that I've used a *jQuery plugin* here:

[**floatthead**](https://github.com/mkoryak/floatThead)

Comment: But there is no horizontal scrollbar..i need both scrollbar

Comment: @20prj glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
th, td {
    width: 49px;
}
table table
{
    border: none;
}
```

might help you and if you could remove BG Image from first row and use normal color then height of row will also be managed.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyCKE/7035/)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hem8whqa/).

I changed your html to single table

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Header 1</th>
            <th>Header 2</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new itemmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>new item</td>
            <td>new item</td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

and added this css

```
tbody {
     display: block;
     height: 200px;
     width: 300px;
     overflow-y: auto;
     overflow-x: auto;
 }
```